# Crawler reverse error execjs._exceptions.ProgramError: SyntaxError: syntax error

Tags: javascript, python

I think there is no problem with my js file and py file. The js file can run the results separately, but this syntax error will be reported when calling the js file using the execjs module in the py file.Is it an environmental problem?

```
#my code
import execjs


js = '''
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>');
window = global;
var document = dom.window.document;
function signature(){
    return 1
}
'''
ct = execjs.compile(js).call("signature")
print(ct)
```

Comment: PyExecJS has been abandoned in [2018](https://gist.github.com/doloopwhile/8c6ec7dd4703e8a44e559411cb2ea221). Are you sure it supports this ES6 syntax?

Comment: Is there a python library that supports me to do this (py files call js files and support ES6 syntax)?@bfontaine

Comment: I don’t know. Depending on your use-case you could use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) with `node`.